# How to properly pass data to sibling component using VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Let's say I have `CountrySelect` and `CitySelect`, where in `CountrySelect` are listed all countries and in `CitySelect` are only listed those cities of currently selected country...

What would the proper way to pass newly selected country. As I have read in vuejs documentation:

> In Vue, the parent-child component relationship can be summarized as props down, events up. The parent passes data down to the child via props, and the child sends messages to the parent via events. Let’s see how they work next.

So in this case, I would detect change of select box inside of `CountrySelect` and fire event `changed` and along with it a country object. Then the parent component of `CountrySelect` would listen for this event and then when that happens will update its attribute `country`. Attribute `country` is "observed" in parent component and changing its value will cause for DOM to update, so HTML attribute on `<city-select>` tag called `country` would change. But then how would I detect property change of `CitySelect` component, since I need to reload cities via AJAX. I think of putting `country` property in `watch` object in `CitySelect` but that does not seems like an elegant solution to me, it doesn't feels quire right to do...

```
<template>
    <parent>
        <country-select name="country_id" v-model="country"></country-select>
        <city-select name="city_id" :country="country" v-model="city"></city-select>
    </parent>
<template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                country: null,
                city: null,
            };
        }
    }
</script>
```

Other way around that I think is if do something like this in parent:

```
this.$refs.citySelect.emit('countryChanged', this.country)
```

or:

```
this.$refs.citySelect.countryChanged(this.country)
```

I do not know if these two are possible... So what would be the correct way for `CountrySelect` component to tell to its sibling component `CitySelect` to update cities list...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By passing `country` as a property to your `CitySelect` component, you are *already* doing what you need to do. When `country` changes, the changed value will be passed to the `CitySelect` component. You simply need to make sure your `CitySelect` component is aware of the changes.

Here is a working example.

```js
console.clear()

// Simulated service for retrieving cities by country
const CityService = {
  cities: [
    {id: 1, country: "USA", name: "New York"},
    {id: 2, country: "USA", name: "San Francisco"},
    {id: 3, country: "USA", name: "Boston"},
    {id: 4, country: "USA", name: "Chicago"},
    {id: 5, country: "England", name: "London"},
    {id: 6, country: "England", name: "Bristol"},
    {id: 7, country: "England", name: "Manchester"},
    {id: 8, country: "England", name: "Leeds"},
  ],
  getCities(country){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(this.cities.filter(city => city.country === country)), 250)
    })
  }
}

Vue.component("CountrySelect",{
  props: ["value"],
  template: `
  <select v-model="selectedCountry">
    <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country">{{country}}</option>
  </select>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      countries: ["USA", "England"]
    }
  },
  computed:{
    selectedCountry:{
      get(){return this.value},
      set(v){this.$emit('input', v)}
    }
  }
})

Vue.component("CitySelect", {
  props: ["value", "country"],
  template: `
  <select v-model="selectedCity">
    <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city">{{city.name}}</option>
  </select>
  `,
  data(){
    return {
      cities: []
    }
  },
  computed:{
    selectedCity:{
      get(){return this.value},
      set(v){this.$emit('input', v)}
    }
  },
  watch:{
    country(newCountry){
      // simulate an AJAX call to an external service
      CityService.getCities(newCountry).then(cities => this.cities = cities)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    country: null,
    city: null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <country-select v-model="country"></country-select>
  <city-select :country="country" v-model="city"></city-select>
  <hr>
  Selected Country: {{country}} <br>
  Selected City: {{city}}
</div>
```

Comment: So you have created computed property that uses `country` property and because that, `filteredCities` is recalculateded each time `country` is changed, because it depends on it? And when `filteredCities` is recalculated the DOM is updated... But I want to use AJAX, and in that case how would I fetch new list of cities based on country id (`/api/lists/countries/3/cities`) ....?

Comment: @clzola I was just working on that :) Updated with a simulated AJAX call.

Comment: Aha, so it is just as I mentioned in my question, to "watch" property :D thanks

Comment: @clzola I think a watch is the most appropriate way here. You *could* use a computed, but async computed values are generally a bad idea.