# Vue.js: pass data from one child component to another with the same parent?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 2 components, both sharing a common parent. I want to be able to pass data from one child component to the other. (I am using vueJS 2)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html  The one child can emit an event to provide data to the parent, who can then provide that data to the second child via a property.  Or, both children can share a service that acts as the master record keeper.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48190694/how-to-properly-pass-data-to-sibling-component-using-vuejs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The communication should be handled by the `parent` component as follows:

1. Child 1 sends the data to parent

```
this.$emit('myVarChanged', this.myVar);
```

2. The parent listens to the emits from the last, saves the new value, and pass it to the second child:

```
<ChildOneComponent @myVarChanged="updateMyVar" />
```

```
data() { return { myVar:null } }
```

```
methods: {
     updateMyVar(val){
          this.myVar = val;
     }
}
```

```
<ChildTwoComponent :myVar="myVar" />
```

3. Child 2 gets the new value as `props`:

```
props: ['myVar']
```

**Demo:**

```js
const child1 = Vue.component('child1', {
  template: '#child1',
  data() { return { count:0 } },
  methods: {
    updateParent() { this.$emit('myvarchanged', this.count++); }
  }
});

const child2 = Vue.component('child2', {
  template: '#child2',
  props: ['myvar']
});

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  components: { child1, child2 },
  data() { return { myvar:null } },
  methods: {
    updateMyVar(val) { this.myvar = val; }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template id="child1">
  <div>
    <h1>Child 1</h1>
    <button @click="updateParent">Click to send to child 2</button>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="child2">
  <div>
    <h1>Child 2</h1>
    <p>Prop from child 1: {{myvar}}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <div><child1 @myvarchanged="updateMyVar" /></div>
  <div><child2 :myvar="myvar" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've repeated the exact same pattern in my project and what happens is that the parent receives the data that is listening on but it does not pass it to the child. It seems that the data is not reactive anymore, at least for this communication. To check it, I've set up a watcher on the prop of the final child, but it does not react. I've finally implemented the "update" hook in this child, but nothing... Maybe I am wrong, but it looks like that the only walkable paths are bus or Vuex.

Comment: @TommasoMazza once the parent updates the state, it's reflected in the second child's props. You can share a simple fiddle to explain your scenario

Comment: My scenario overlaps your schema above. Unless I've made other mistakes, unfortunately, it does not work. The parent gets updated, but does not propagate the prop downward. If you have a working fiddle it would be very useful.

Comment: @TommasoMazza I added a demo to the answer to help you debug the issue

Comment: Thank you. I've upvoted your answer. In the meantime, I've understood the problem in my project. I'm using vuetify and I have a v-tabs. For some reason, props are propagated in all components within tabs correctly but are not "watched" until I visit the tab for the first time... Not clear to me why. Thank you for your example, that is useful anyway.